# Running the test method throwing error for SoftAssert-java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I have written a test method by importing-import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
Although the compilation is successful while running the test method through Jenkins throwing error as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the code of your test method?

Comment: Any suggestions on this issue ?